# Defalut routing not working after adding route attribute in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I created an mvc project with no attribute route. It was working fine. When I added an attribute route `[Route("employeehome")]` on one of my action methods, the conventional routing `{controller}/{action}/{id}` ie `employee/index` for that method ceased working. Is there anything wrong with my approach?

Adding my code snippet.

Route Config Code.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Controller code.

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Employee
    [Route("employeehome")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Comment: Show you `RouteConfig` class. Moreover edit your question, especially code area.

Comment: Conventional routing and attribute routing are not mutually exclusive. You can use one or both simultaneously. If the route is not working, there's some other issue you've introduced. However, with no code, it's impossible to say what that might be.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Added Code snippet. Please let me know if any further detail is needed.